# Add div attribute when resize window in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

My code is:

```
<div id="column-left">
     Test
</div>
```

When the window size is smaller than 640px, how can I change it as:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="left">
     Test
</div>
```

Testing Hints: As the code is in Jquerymobile, if success, after it's small than 640, the panel will be hidden automatically.

Comment: @Omar Yes, I am trying to ask in different way, which focus on adding attribute to div and see if there is any better result. I saw your solution but I think it's a little bit complex and too heavy. I wonder if it's more straight forward solution to just adding the data-role attribute after resize!

Comment: I understand you. Adding attribute is easy, but creating a _panel_ won't work by just adding _attributes_. _Panel_ should be created and parent _page_ should be updated with _panel_ classes.